# DLL cannot use address in executable

Tags: winapi, pointers, dll, assembly, win64

I'm writing a console application in 64bit NASM, and everything was fine until I moved part of my executable into a DLL I created.
This is my first experiment with DLL's at an assembly level.
I cannot pass an address of a string in my .exe's data section...
The function fails when I do. But, if I make a .data section in my dll, define the string, and pass it in RCX to SetConsoleTitleA it runs like a charm.

Am I not passing the correct address, or is the DLL unable to get into the data section of my EXE?
What would be a "elegant" solution to this?

Let me know if you'd like me to pastebin the code.

EDIT:
DLL http://pastebin.com/jpdsihsC
EXE http://pastebin.com/KbMTh9Xa

--ignore inc.mac, it's for forward dev

Comment: Passing in an address should work, so go ahead and pastebin the code.

Comment: I hope you have handled that `AllocConsole` may clobber `rcx`, that is if you simply pass in your title into `newconsole` using `rcx`, it won't survive until `SetConsoleTitleA`.

Comment: Are you loading `r9` in the EXE but using `r8` in the DLL?

Comment: Not for the title issue @A.Webb, but I may have to look into that too

Comment: @Jester Thanks, I didn't know it would. Is there anywhere I can find what registers are preserved and which aren't using the winapi? The MSDN article I find when searching AllocConsole [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't delve into assembly...

Comment: It's not `AllocConsole` as such, it's the general calling convention. See [msdn page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b372w95%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).